# Converting from 1.7 to 1.9 and cannot get RWD theme to work

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, rwd

I am converting an existing multi store Magento 1.7 to 1.9 and cannot get the rwd theme to work. I want to appy a custom theme but thought that I should get RWD working first.

After conversion the Magento 1.7 default theme shows up.

I used a copy of my production DB and an app/etc/local.xml  corrected for the test DB and loaded the site to get the database upgraded.
In Admin I changed the package to rwd and cleared out the theme, info for other scopes.

What is preventing the rwd to show?

I can make a new 1.9 install and it works as advertized including the RWD theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say there are only two likely causes for this. A) a scoping/configuration issue, which it sounds like you have covered but it might pay to double check. or B) caching, have you flushed the magento cache?

Comment: Good advice, but no change.

Comment: If you can do a clean install ok then it must be db related. You don't have any third party theme switching extensions, perhaps for mobile/desktop themes?

Comment: Maybe try select * from core_config_data where value like "%oldtheme%"; to see if you can find any leftover config.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I removed config entries for old theme and then even all config entries except the 16 original entries from a clean, working install..

Comment: Following in this thinking I searched the whole database for the theme name and found and deleted it in themeframework_area and got the RWD!